# Conditional density of two jointly gaussian random vectors

Tags: probability, statistics

In my estimation theory textbook, the following is stated as a reminder without any further explanation:

Consider the gaussian random vector
$\bf{z} = \begin{pmatrix}\bf{x} \\ \bf{y}\end{pmatrix}$ with mean $\hat{z} = \begin{pmatrix}\hat{x} \\ \hat{y}\end{pmatrix}$ and covariance matrix $\bf{C}_z = \begin{pmatrix} \bf{C}_{xx} & \bf{C}_{xy} \\ \bf{C}_{yx} & \bf{C}_{yy} \end{pmatrix}$

If a measurement $y^*$ is given, the conditional density of $x$ conditioned on that measurement $f\left(x | y^*\right)$ is gaussian with mean

$\hat{x} + \bf{C}_{xy}\bf{C}_{yy}^{-1} \left( y^* - \hat{y} \right)$

and covariance matrix

$\bf{C}_{xx} - \bf{C}_{xy} \bf{C}_{yy}^{-1} \bf{C}_{yx}$

(Pseudo-inverses replace inverses when necessary)

Having never worked with conditional densities before, I don't see how to derive these formulas, or what the intuition behind them is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A detailed proof with carefully presented computations is [**here**](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e161/lectures/gaussianprocess/node7.html), see Part b of Theorem 4.